# spring boot - generating large csv file drops Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Controller action generates CSV content and returns it with header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv`

```
    @GetMapping("/csv")
    public void csvEmissions(HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {

            ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<CsvRow> mapStrategy
                    = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();
            mapStrategy.setType(CsvRow.class);

            String[] columns = new String[]{
                    "col1",
                    "col2"
            };
            mapStrategy.setColumnMapping(columns);

            CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(response.getWriter());

            StatefulBeanToCsv<CsvRow> btcsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<CsvRow>(response.getWriter())
                    .withMappingStrategy(mapStrategy)
                    .withSeparator(',')
                    .build();

            btcsv.write(csvrows());

            response.setContentType("text/csv");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.csv");
            csvWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException | CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException | CsvDataTypeMismatchException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

all works fine when there is not much `CsvRow` returned by `csvrows()` method. File is properly downloaded by the browser.

When rows count is larger (let's say over 200) it drops `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` header and browser prints CSV output as a text in the browser.

Only `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header is present in the response.

Any suggestions how to make it downloadable for large amount of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Header `Content-Length` is missing from your response that's why large content is being fetched into chunks and browser displays into tab.

To get the content length try saving csv data into temporary file before putting it to response.
Also set the headers before writing data to response writer.

```
File file = createTempCSVFile();

response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.csv");

// write file data to response.getWriter();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I added `response.setContentLength(response.getBufferSize());` line just below `setContentType` with no luck :(

Comment: @hopsey, buffer size is not the actual size of the content, so it won't work. Have you tried it with temp file creation?

Comment: moving csv output to temp file helped, event without setting content length header. Thank you!